# rsync -aviuP misses unfinished or corrupt files

Tags: shell, rsync

When I  run the command:

`rsync -aviuP /src /trgt`

The command seems to be missing some files that are not correct at the target destination. Like a 25gb file on src, being 4gb at the target and corrupt. I run the command 3 times to be safe.

When I start the sync, I have to stop the sync with `ctrl+C` every now and then as I need the drives to work faster for some other task but I thought the P flag was meant to make that cosher.

Am I missing something here? The problem is happening relatively frequently and I can't seem to find any answers on the web.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid interrupting the sync process. Instead limit the maximum bandwidth used by rsync using the `bwlimit` option

```
rsync --bwlimit=1000 -aviuP /src /trgt
```

In this example the maximum bandwidth used would be limited to roughly 1MB/s (1000KB/s).

Comment: Thank you maxhb I will use the bwlimit as you suggested.